# Difference between "@property(nonatomic, strong)" and "@property"

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, properties, declaration

What is the difference between these two declarations in Objective-C?

I have been looking at some Apple source code example and they used the second one in various circumstances. I just wanted to understand why and when is best to use the second version rather than the first one (I know the difference between **strong, weak, atomic, nonatomic**).

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSObject * myObject;
```

// vs

```
@property NSObject * myObject2;  //No additional qualifiers
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@property NSObject * myObject2

// is same as
@property (atomic,strong) NSObject * myObject2
```

which one to use, is developer's personal choice

Comment: Other than the technical stuff it's a preference thing. Some developers might like to be more explicit in there declarations and include the qualifiers even if they are the default once.